# @Html.Partial, different controller, does not work after publish

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I have two controllers:

- PeopleController
- UnitController

And I have a few views,

- /People/_Create (partial View)
- /Unit/Edit

There is a modal dialog in /Unit/Edit with the following HTML:

```
<div id="Person-CreateNew" class="tab-pane fade in active">
   @Html.Partial("../People/_Create", new Person())
</div>
```

This works fine when I run from Visual Studio, but If I publish, then run using `dotnet myproject.dll`, I get "Cannot find view _Create...Searched /Units/_Create, /Shared/Units/_Create ...."

How can I make this work after publish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using relative paths, you should always use full paths:

```
<div id="Person-CreateNew" class="tab-pane fade in active">
   @Html.Partial("~/Views/People/_Create", new Person())
</div>
```

This will continue to work after the view compilation process.

Though, notice that using the asynchronous version of `Partial` is recommended:

```
<div id="Person-CreateNew" class="tab-pane fade in active">
   @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/People/_Create", new Person())
</div>
```

Comment: Be aware that `Html.Partial` can cause deadlocks. It's recommended to use `await Html.PartialAsync` or use `<partial>` tag helper. More info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-2.1#synchronous-html-helper

Comment: @tura08 I've never had a deadlock caused by `Html.Partial`, but that sounds like a fair warning. I'm glad I always default to async methods. So, thanks!